# multiple list with list of objects

Tags: java, c#

I have 2 lists. Each list consists of objects in it, i.e, list of objects.

```
List<Book> listBook= new List<Book>();
List<Pen> listPen = new List<Pen>();

class Book {
    string name;
    int id;

    Book() {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class Pen {
    string name;
    int id;

    Pen() {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

`listBook` has 10 objects in it and same with `listPen` it has 10 objects.

I need a single `add` method by passing reference of list object or list with details, list has to get updated.
I mean, single method, calling that method with list-pen or list-book should add new objects to list-pen or list-book respectively.

Thanks for any suggestions or helping with any

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5761558/ernest-k instead of formatting the code please help me with the logic if any thanks for formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, so I will suggest a few solutions base on my assumption that you are using C#:

Case 1: if you simply want to add an item to a list, use Ling then.

```
using System.Linq;

List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
Book myBook = new Book();
books.Add(myBook);
```

Case 2: if you want to create a method that works with any data type, write a template then

```
public void MyAddMethod<T>(ref List<T> list, T item)
{
    list.Add(item);
}

List<Book> book = new List<Book>();
Book myBook = new Book();
MyAddMethod(ref books, myBook);
```

That 's my best bet. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks it works perfectly ,sorry i cant  up vote up because of my reputation which is not to the limit required

Comment: can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generics for this. As below `addToList` method is a generic method, which accept any type of list and object to add it.

```
public static <T> void addToList(final List<T> list, final T toAdd) {

    list.add(toAdd);
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final List<Book> listBook = new ArrayList<Book>();
    final List<Pen> listPen = new ArrayList<Pen>();

    addToList(listPen, new Pen());
    addToList(listBook, new Book());
  }
```

Note (Out of the Question) : In your code you have created Object of `List`, while List is an Interface, so you can't create Object of List. Rather it should be of `ArrayList()`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for only one method(i.e. Add()) ,here is the complete code.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace Rextester
{

    public class Book
    {
        public string name;
        public int id;
        public Book(string name, int id)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    public class Pen
    {
        public string name;
        public int id;
        public Pen(string name, int id)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        static List<Book> listBook = new List<Book>();
        static List<Pen> listPen = new List<Pen>();
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            listBook.Add(new Book
            (
                 "Book1",
             1
            ));
            listBook.Add(new Book
        ("Book2",
              2
            ));



            listPen.Add(new Pen
        ("Pen1",
                 1
            ));
            listPen.Add(new Pen("Pen2", 2));



            //Testing with new book list

            List<Book> newListBook = new List<Book>();
            newListBook.Add(new Book
            ("Book3",
                  3
            ));
            newListBook.Add(new Book
            ("Book4",
                  4
            ));

            Add(newListBook);

            foreach (var item in listBook)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.name);

            }


            List<Pen> newListPen = new List<Pen>();
            newListPen.Add(new Pen
            ("Pen3",
                  3
            ));
            newListPen.Add(new Pen
            ("Pen4",
                  4
            ));

            Add(newListPen);

            foreach (var item in listPen)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.name);

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> obj)
        {
            foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                if (item is Book)
                {
                    listBook.Add(item as Book);

                }
                if (item is Pen)
                {
                    listPen.Add(item as Pen);

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```